# Why I can not initialize value in useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

tiles is an array of objects

```
    var intialTiles = tiles;
    const [newTiles, setNewTiles] = useState(intialTiles);
```

when I console log newTiles i see undefined , what could be the reson ?

Comment: I guess that `tiles` is `undefined`

Comment: Could you include how you get tiles?

Comment: Not particularly relevant, but looks like a typo of `initialTiles`.

Comment: Yes tiles coming from props and I just realized in initial render that is undefined, although I do not know how I can use that to initialize state , may be a useEffect ?

Comment: did you have a look at the sample?

Comment: yes I did , do not think so that will help in my case

Comment: I have updated it now

Comment: <App tiles={[123, 4546]} />

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-bash-23o700?file=/src/App.js

Comment: thanks @DreamBold , I got some idea , actually in my case button is updating the array not setting the tiles, so in any case I need initialTiles to be same as tiles, hence i did something like this which is working , setButton state to true and if that is true use the newly loaded tiles

Comment: Perfect, let me add it as an answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

You can send the props to the component this way,  `<App tiles={[123, 4546]} />`

And in the App component,

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App(props) {
  var intialTiles = props.tiles;
  const [newTiles, setNewTiles] = useState(intialTiles);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(newTiles);
  }, [newTiles]);

  function update() {
    setNewTiles([...newTiles, parseInt(Math.random() * 2345, 10)]);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={update}>update</button>
      <h2>Please check the console output</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hope it helps! live demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-bash-23o700?file=/src/App.js:0-506